# python replace all special characters and spaces with single '-'

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to replace all the special characters and spaces in the string with only single '-'

For example:

Input: `"Games & Fun"`

Output: `"Games-Fun"`

I tried

```
>>> re.sub('[&" "]', '-', "Games & Fun")
'Games---Fun'
```

But I want `"Games-Fun"` only.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What if you use something like \W+ for non-word characters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Games & Fun"
>>> re.sub(r'\W+', '-', text)
'Games-Fun'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> re.sub(r'[&\s]+', '-', "Games & Fun")
'Games-Fun'
```